# Is there a way where I can restart lotus automatically when windows system is started and after crash?

Tags: boot, operating-systems, crash, lotus-notes

I am aware that some files can be loaded when OS boots so that the launch of Lotus gets faster but is there a way I can launch Lotus completely and even in case of a crash, can i launch lotus without doing the clean up of leftover lotus tasks.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the application program into your startup folder.  Thus when you login, it will automatically start for you.

BTW, my answer assumes a Windows envrionment.

Your note did not, unfortunately, mention OS, distribution and version.

Comment: Found 2 ways: adding to startup as you mentioned. Thanks for that and from IBM end there is a way for auto-restart after crash(http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/IBM_Notes_Client_-_Automatic_Restart_after_an_abnormal_termination)

Comment: I am using Win 7 and Lotus notes 9 Social edition. It's little slower while booting up but it works. Thanks again.